# DigitalOcean Server CPU 100% without app running

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean, pm2

`htop` command shows the CPU is 100% used even tho I do not have the app running or anything else. The DigitalOcean dashboard metric shows this same data (100% usage) as well.

[image: CPU 100%]

The top tasks on the `htop` list take less than 10% CPU usage. The biggest is pm2 taking ~5.2 % usage.

Is it possible that there are hidden tasks that are not displaying on the list and, in general, how I can start investigating what's going on?

My droplet used this one-click installation:
https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/nodejs

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1)**

The droplet has a lot of free disk space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran `pm2 save --force` to sync running processes and the CPU went back to normal.

I guess there was an app stuck or something that ate all the CPU.

Comment: Didn't help 
Do you happen to have anythings else tried simultaneously or happen to find some more info regarding this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I used htop, top, ps aux there is no process that is using CPU. So stop PM2 and kill all the node processes using `pkill -f node` command, which worked for me.